# visual studio 2012, postbuild event, bat file not creating new file (not executing)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, batch-file, post-build-event

I have a bat file with code:

```
echo Hello There > Result.txt
@exit 0
```

File is located in folder named "batch" which is located in the project root.

I am calling it with this code in post-build event:

```
call "$(ProjectDir)batch\post.bat"
```

I am using @exit 0 because otherwise I get error code 1 (which I guess tells me that command didn't succeed).

When I double click on bat file or invoke it from cmd it creates a file.
What do I need to do in order to make this work

EDIT:
Guys, make sure your file is in ASCII encoding. I've created mine with VS which sets encoding to UTF by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change you batch file to receive as first parameter the $(ProjectDir) macro and then change the PostBuild event to pass this macro

Post.bat

```
echo Hello There > %1%Result.txt
@exit 0
```

PostBuild event

```
call "$(ProjectDir)batch\post.bat" $(ProjectDir)batch\
```

Your previous command fails because the postbuild event is executed inside the Current Output directory of your executable (usually BIN\DEBUG or RELEASE). You could easily check this adding a dir command with a redirection to the result.txt in the above example

Comment: This was it, when I finally got it working... The problem was that I created bat file with visual studio dialog and got some utf chars messing up my script. Found out that while testing script in cmdline - saw some strange characters appearing and text not echoed into new file. Solved by creating new file in native notepad - ascii. You were right, file was initially created in bin folder. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Check the project directory for the file, since the batch file is being run, but with a current directory of $(ProjectDir)   and not in the batch directory.