# Visual Studio 2017 are not running powershell scripts from .csproj

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, powershell, asp.net-core

I have a .csproj file with this code:

`<Target Name="PrecompileScript" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
    <Exec Command="powershell -file $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\..\settings\copy-settings.ps1 $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)" />
</Target>`

It should copy setting from one folder to another.

But after building project, I have an error with message

`Severity Code Description  Project File Line Suppression State
Error MSB3073 The command "powershell -file <path> exited with code 1.`

If I'm trying to run this script from Windows cmd, it is successful.

How I should run the script from .csproj file?

Comment: Script: `$projectFolder = $args[0]
$settingsFolder = $PSScriptRoot
cp $settingsFolder $projectFolder -force -recurse`

Comment: its usually an invalid path or incorrect working directory. have you checked both? as you said from windows cmd it works what about from a a different folder?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25032231/why-do-all-pre-build-or-post-build-events-in-visual-studio-fail-with-exit-code-1

Comment: @Digvijay paths are correct. Maybe it's because of braces or quotes. But I tried different ways, and didn't get a result.

Comment: maybe the exit 0 as suggested by @David Brabant

Comment: Can you run this command/script successfully from command line? Is script execution enabled?